# loop through www folder phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

Hi I'm creating a simple framework that needs to loop through a folder, that is stored in the www folder, in my phonegap project. At the moment I'm using the fileSystem.root to list al files in a folder but as root suggests, it only shows all the items in my phones root folder. Is there a way to get the directory of the www directory?

Comment: for both android and iphone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The content of the www folder is read only. There is no need to read the content at runtime as it is always the same. It would be better to read the files during build phase and save the result in a JSON file or something that you include in the app.

Comment: thank you for your reaction. the problem is that i don't know how to do this.

Comment: if you have a node.js based workflow, you can create a script being this package https://www.npmjs.org/package/glob.

Answer (score 0):

Since in PhoneGap app your app runs in the webview with **www** directory, you can simply extract the www path as below:

```
var wwwDirectoryPath = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf("/www"));
```

It will give you the folder path in which 'www' folder resides.